# Is possible to use ESP8266 as a network adapter?

Tags: wifi, iot, esp8266, mqx

I have a IoT solution based on Freescale/NXP FRDM-K64 board and the MQX operating system, communicating to the Internet with Ethernet. Now I would like to change from Ethernet to Wi-Fi.

The ESP8266 (or another module under $10) can provide a mechanism to operate as a network adapter, ignoring the internal IP stack and sending the "low-level packages" to the Ethernet/IP stack already implemented in the current solution (something like a "totally transparent and bidirecional bridge")?

Furthermore, this Wi-Fi module can listen multiple ports simultaneously, for example: 80/443 for HTTP/S and 161 for SNMP?

If this requires a custom ESP firmware or some MQX modifications, can you provide some guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

With the [Espressif SDK 1.5.2 for the ESP8266](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=850) it's not possible to send "low-level packages". You can send UDP packets or can establish TCP connections. But unfortunaly there is no API for sending only packets.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias. Can you provide some guidelines how would be send UDP packages over serial connection? I think TCP would be possible too, right? I think I could send these packages to the MQX stack. Do you think ESP8266 could listen to multiple ports simultaneously?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the ESP8266 AT commands. For that you need the AT command firmware. http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1703 Take a look at the at command documentation and the examples. http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=1022 I'm not sure if you can create multiple TCP servers at the same time. But with AT+CIPMODE you can set the UART-WiFi passthrough mode.